# Where does main or UI thread in android prepare looper?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

It seems that in the main thread I just need to write a class that extends Handler and override its handleMessage method. Then I can just create Handler object without prepare looper.

```
class myHandler extends Handler{

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        String s=(String)msg.obj;
        textView.setText(s);
    }
}
```

In the main thread, following code works:

```
handler=new myHandler();
```

But in the worker thread you do need to prepare looper first and then you can create Handler object, otherwise threadLocal.get() can not get looper for the current worker thread. My question is there must be somewhere that prepare the looper for main thread but I just can not find it. I don not know how threadLocal find this looper for main thread.

```
class WorkerThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        Looper.prepare();
        handler=new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                System.out.println(msg.obj.toString());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }

        };

        Looper.loop();
    }

}
```

Comment: see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#5401)

Comment: I want to know exact same question. When does the main thread Looper prepared. Its sure it does not prepare itself in Application class. you cant create Handler in Application class.

Answer (score 1):

Main looper is prepared in the main method of class ActivityThread with the following method call:

```
Looper.prepareMainLooper();
```

See source code for example [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#6642).

Comment: actually this is the exact answer, though It seems the OP didn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define Looper in you main thread.

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

you can call this method from main thread or other worker thread.Be cautious.

```
void timerMethod(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setTime();
        }
    }, timeDelay);
}
```